# How to get a Url segment in django

Tags: php, python, django

In php's Codeigniter, the uri class (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) has the ability to retrieve a url segment using:

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

Is there an equivalent abilty in Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a part of the standard Python library, in the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module.

```
import urlparse
path = urlparse.urlsplit(uri).path
print path.split('/')[n]
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Daniel -

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter uses a segment-based approach which, by default, imposes url structured as follows: `class/function/ID`.

Django lets you design URLs however you want, with no framework limitations so there is no need of a URL helper like the one in CI.